# HTML / PHP scrollbar not showing up on iPad but shows on desktops and laptops

Tags: php, html, ipad

scrollbar not showing up for the following textbox on the iPad when I fill it with text.

```
<textarea type="text" name="holyCow" rows="30" cols="120"></textarea></p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mobile Safari doesn't show scrollbars (except the temporary one when you're scroll the entire page). Older versions of iOS require a two-finger drag to scroll interior elements, newer versions use a normal one-finger drag.

If you really need (or want) a scrollbar for the iPad, I've had reasonable success with [TouchScroll](https://github.com/davidaurelio/TouchScroll) but I don't know if you can add that to a `<textarea>`.